# Rules for line split

Tags: c#

Is there a guide where I can read up on the rules of breaking lines to keep within columns?

I have the following code and my margin is set to 80 characters (so that it fits into an A4 page when I print):

```
IDictionary<string, object> columns = new Dictionary<string, object>(1);
```

The parantheses fall just at the 80th column.  So, should I break it up like this:

```
IDictionary<string, object> columns = new Dictionary<string, object>
    (1);
```

or this:

```
IDictionary<string, object> columns = new Dictionary
    <string, object>(1);
```

or this:

```
IDictionary<string, object> columns =
    new Dictionary<string, object>(1);
```

or any other way? I prefer not to increase the margin.

Thanks.

Comment: It really doesn't matter, BUT using var would shorten those declarations.

Comment: @MitchWheat If this is a field initializer, you can't use var.  It would also change the meaning (always) since it's being set to an interface.

Comment: doesn't look like a field initialiser...but true I missed the Interface bit....

Comment: @MitchWheat No way to know if it's a field initializer from the code posted, is there?

Comment: That's right: no way to know either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

80 characters in line is not a law - it's nice to have. And best option here is:

```
var columns = new Dictionary<string, object>(1);
```

**Never** break type name, generic parameters, and opening bracket (it's OK to continue on next line if you have many parameters). So, options also (the best one - forget about 80 characters and put all into one line):

```
IDictionary<string, object> columns = new Dictionary<string, object>(1);
```

and (if line is really long)

```
IDictionary<string, object> columns = 
        new Dictionary<string, object>(1);
```

or split assignment and declaration

```
IDictionary<string, object> columns;
columns = new Dictionary<string, object>(1);
```

Comment: Note that this does actually change the meaning, in this case.  (It probably doesn't matter, but this is not identical to the original statement)

Comment: @ReedCopsey you mean last one? Yes it will go only for local variables.

Comment: I meant the first (using var), since it's assigning to the interface, not the type.  Using `var` will cause it to create the variable as a `Dictionary<T,U>`, not `IDictionary<T,U>`...

Comment: @ReedCopsey, good remark. Actually var is available only for local variables, so we already know exact type, and we can remove unnecessary abstraction. But +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

This is really a matter of personal preference and convention.

My preference, if you must split, would be your last option:

```
IDictionary<string, object> columns =
    new Dictionary<string, object>(1);
```

I only say this because the other options all split in the middle of the expression - in the first case, you're splitting the constructor parameters into their own line, and the second you're breaking the type definition into two lines.  In this case, the entire statement (constructor with parameters) is kept together.

That being said, I would probably not split this in general.  I'd probably let it bleed past 80 characters (there isn't really anything wrong with that normally).